# Basic auth in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

Всем доброго времени суток! С помощью axios посылаю GET запрос к API с имеющимся токеном, но возвращается такой ответ:
[image: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.]
как исправить? на данный момент приложение состоит из созданой директории с помощью  create-react-app ... запрос посылаю в методе componentDidMount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
const instance = axios.create({
  method: 'get',
  withCredentials: true,
  responseType: 'json',
  responseEncoding: 'utf8',
});

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://domen/api/organization';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'MY_TOKEN';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

instance()
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

}

Comment: надо что бы сервер возвращал правильные заголовки https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @ThisMan , я так понимаю что нужно написать свой сервер(express допустим) и уже от туда слать запрос?